# No module named '__builtin__' while running torch.load(f"{SaveFolder}/model.pt", map_location = torch.device('cpu'))

Tags: pytorch, built-in

I'm trying to load a previously trained model using the following:

```
model = torch.load(f"{SaveFolder}/model.pt", map_location = torch.device('cpu'))
```

SaveFolder has the correct path of the previously saved fully trained model. And this is the error I'm getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxHQa.png)

Comment: are you using Python2 instead of Python3 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `pip install future` and see if that clears the issue up.